# Что значит regexp в библиотеке PyTelegramBotAPI?

Tags: python, telebot

Искал в интернете - ничего не нашел. Возможно потому, что мой вопрос слишком глуп, но все-же: я не понимаю. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```py
@bot.message_handler(regexp="SOME_REGEXP")
def handle_message(message):
    pass
```

Comment: [«Handles all messages which text matches regexp»](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/__init__.py#L1772), «:param regexp: Optional regular expression.»

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Обрабатывать сообщение только если оно соответствует регулярке.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Иван, ответ прими нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: Ну отлично, ещё и минусы за правильный ответ.

Comment: Я не могу голосовать. Это не мог быть я.

Comment: @Иван 1. Я и не говорил, что ты. 2. Зато, если ответ устраивает, ты можешь ответ принять галочкой слева от него.

Comment: Спасибо большое!